# Is First method async in Linq?

Tags: linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm pretty new to dotnet asp core and would like to use async methods to talk with the database to follow good practices.

In a scenario I'm facing I need to retrieve First record of a table that matches a condition. It could or could not exist. So, I use the method using Entity Framework dbContext.mytable.First but it seems it isn't asyncronous.

Should I get rid of it and just use dbContext.mytable.FindAsync?

Comment: You are probably missing a reference https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions.firstasync?view=efcore-3.1 note the namespace and assembly

Comment: First() will throw an exception if the record does not exist, instead you can use FirstOrDefault , so the return value will be null in case the record does not exist and no exeption will be thrown.

Comment: None of the normal LINQ methods are asynchronous. They would need a return type of `Task<something>` to be async.

Comment: Good point, but, should I still use a non async method in a action controller? Everyone seems to agree only async functions should  be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably missing a reference

[EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.FirstAsync Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions.firstasync?view=efcore-3.1)

note the namespace and assembly

```
Namespace:    Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
Assembly:    Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll
```

That should allow the use of `FirstAsync`

```
var result = await dbContext.mytable.FirstAsync(x => x.property == something);
```

If there is a possibility that the record does not exist then use [`FirstOrDefaultAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions.firstordefaultasync?view=efcore-3.1)

```
var result = await dbContext.mytable.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.property == something);
```